# CKEDITOR toolbar is not showing up fully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am getting a weird behavior using CKEDITOR with Rails, I tried both of those gems :  [ckeditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)  and [ckeditor_rails gem](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails) in different app I have (Rails v4.2.0 and with Rails v4.2.1 and Rails v4.2.2)

I have a text with id="ck"

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="ck">some dummy text</p>
```

and I am using the inline editing option

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline("ck");
});
```

In my Rails 4.2.1 and 4.2.2 I noticed that the toolbar does not show all buttons, while it show all buttons (I mean full toolbar) for my Rails 4.2.0

So my hypotheses was that there are maybe some bugs within the the last versions of rails... so I created a new gemset and I installed Rails 4.2.0 to see if it will still work, but it doesn't !

I am not sure what's wrong... I hope I can get some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who land up on this page searching for an answer. The plugin needs to be used on a div element and not on a p element; here is the same issue with Tinymce [Tinymce align text buttons don't work on inline editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118113/tinymce-align-text-buttons-dont-work-on-inline-editing/31118676?noredirect=1#comment50251648_31118676)

thanks for pointing me to here bro.