# CKEDITOR why Justify buttons and bullet list doesn't show up in the toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I downloaded the full package of CKEDITOR from [here](http://ckeditor.com/download) and created the following code :

HTML :

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="ck">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true
            instance = CKEDITOR.inline( "ck" )
    });
</script>
```

and this is how it looks :

[image: ckeditor toolbar]

I don't know why **Justify text buttons and bullet list** button doesn't appear in the toolbar. I tested that code in **PC and MAC** but it's the same result.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31119901/3941341

And as I see that question was opened by you too.