# Tinymce align text buttons don't work on inline editing

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have the following code :

HTML:

```
<p id="edit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        tinymce.init({ 
        inline : true,
        selector : 'p#edit'
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is how the toolbar look like :

[image: tinymce toolbar]

**text align buttons and bullet list buttons and also indent button are not working**

What's going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried making a p element as an editor but here's my code with a textarea. The key is that you use the right selector and the correct mode.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MarketingInformation, new { @class = "form-control mceEditor" })
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            mode: "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector : "mceEditor",
            height: 100,
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor textcolor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime table contextmenu paste textcolor"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | forecolor backcolor"
        });

</script>
```

I think if you use the mode as 'exact' it should work but I have not tried that; http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:mode

Comment: oh Man you saved my life, I was struggling for a long time with this problem, the issue is that it's doesn't work because I applied the editor to the p tag, I had the same problem with ckeditor and I was wondering why all the editors don't work lol. now I applied it to the div parent and it works. many thanks

Comment: yes of course, this is another question I posted before, you can answer it, I offer a bounty of 50 points, you deserve it :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055735/ckeditor-toolbar-is-not-showing-up-fully

Comment: I think you was misunderstood what I told... they work all on inline editing, just I was using the wrong tag,  I just changed the selector from p to the parent div. it seems that you can't apply the Align text and other buttons directly to the p